# What was Havil's source for the statement that G.H. Hardy would offer his Savillian chair to whoever could prove $\gamma$ irrational?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

In Havil's 2003 book *[Gamma](https://books.google.com/books/about/Gamma.html?id=lQX6Oy_SuOgC)* he states that Hardy offered up his chair in Oxford to whoever could prove that the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ is irrational.

I'm almost positive I had heard a source of this prior to Havil.

But what is the earliest source of this?  Did Hardy really make the offer, and if so was it serious or just as a statement meant to attest to the difficulty of such a question?

**EDIT**

Nick R points to [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) as indicating that there is no written reference for this quote.

So then I'll change my question - what was Havil's source?  His book was quite solid otherwise.

Comment: What are the reasons for not believing that he would really give his chair at Oxford?

Comment: No reason to doubt it, other than idle curiosity about the source of the statement.

Comment: The [WolframMathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html) site states that there is no known written reference for this episode.

Comment: The offer can hardly have been serious, as the appointment of his successor was not in his gift.

Comment: Interestingly enough, despite a published proof,  https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0310/0310404.pdf ,  it appears the math community is not 100% convinced that this proof is correct.  Anyone have further references?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The math community is 100% convinced that "the paper is incorrect, and in many places", see  [Has Euler's Constant  γ  been proven to be irrational? on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147505/has-eulers-constant-gamma-been-proven-to-be-irrational). This author has also "proved" the Goldbach Conjecture, the Twin Primes Conjecture, and the generalized Riemann Hypothesis. Posting on arxiv does not go through peer review, and not everybody is a Perelman.

Comment: @Conifold  thanks;  I'll know to ignore those authors.